# Unable to suppress console output from Bash script

Tags: bash, pipe, io-redirection, stderr

Trying to write a bash script to install and configure samba. Have added a control statement to check if samba is already installed. This takes dpkg output and pipes it into grep and checks if output contains "Status: install ok installed". When output matches the statement works correctly and prints "INFO: $package already installed", but when it doesn't match it outputs dpkg response along with running else block. How do I suppress the output of dpkg when it is unable to match?

```
#!/bin/bash

package="samba"

if dpkg -s "$package" | grep -Fxq "Status: install ok installed"
then
    echo "INFO: $package already installed"
else
    echo "[x] installing $package"
    
    sudo apt update
    echo ""
    sudo apt install samba
fi
```

output (else):

```
dpkg-query: package 'samba' is not installed and no information is available
Use dpkg --info (= dpkg-deb --info) to examine archive files.
[x] installing samba
```

ouput(then)

```
INFO: unzip already installed
```

Comment: Content that isn't seen by grep is necessarily on stderr. `2>/dev/null` suppresses it.

Comment: You could also merge stderr into stdout before it hits the grep.

Comment: tried if dpkg -s "$package" | grep -Fxq "Status: install ok installed" 2>/dev/null but didn't work

Comment: The `2>/dev/null` goes on the `dpkg`, not the `grep` -- it's dpkg, not grep, writing your unwanted message.

Comment: ahh yeah, it was the dpkg thank you!!!